# Openvpn is not authorizing client with error tls handshake failed

Tags: docker, openssl, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN deployed in docker and suddenly OpenVPN is not authorizing to a client to connect to VPN with the error in logs.

```
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XX.XXX.XX.XXX:65336, sid=XXXXXXXXX
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=CRL has expired: CN=vpn-test
OpenSSL: error:140360B2:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:no certificate returned
TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

I have not changed anything from the last 3 months and it was working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not changed anything from the last 3 months and it was working perfectly fine.

That is exactly the problem. In the mean time your CRL expired since you have not renewed it:

```
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=CRL has expired
```

Comment: I generated crl using this commands and managed to connected again but now when I am ssh to the servers in that VPN it is not working :(  `docker exec -it your_openven_container easyrsa gen-crl
docker exec -it your_openvpn_container cp -f "/etc/openvpn/pki/crl.pem" "/etc/openvpn/crl.pem"`